# MySQL query - How to fetch trending rows based on "views", "likes" and "shares" from other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have three tables; `articles`, `likes` and `shares`. I want to fetch, say 50 articles, that have the most combined individual views, likes and shares. This will serve as a query that fetches trending articles based on those three conditions.

I'll describe simplified table structures below:

**articles**

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | title     | views |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 1  | Article 1 |    92 |
| 2  | Article 2 |    14 |
| 3  | Article 3 |    39 |
| 4  | Article 4 |    87 |
| 5  | Article 5 |     8 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

**likes**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | articleID |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |         2 |
| 2  |         3 |
| 3  |         2 |
| 4  |         5 |
| 5  |         3 |
| 6  |         3 |
+----+-----------+
```

**shares**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | articleID | type     |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  |         1 | facebook |
| 2  |         3 | facebook |
| 3  |         1 | twitter  |
| 4  |         4 | twitter  |
| 5  |         2 | facebook |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I am uncertain of the most optimal formula to fetch trending articles. The amount of views per article will always dominate, meaning if I add total views, likes and shares to one summarized value, the result would more or less depend on the highest amount of views:

```
[0] => "Article 1"
[1] => "Article 4"
[2] => "Article 3"
[3] => "Article 2"
[4] => "Article 5"
```

My question is; how do I make an optimal "trending query" based on those three conditions?

### UPDATE

The formula I'm looking for is an overall percentage value based on views, likes and shares. For example, Article 1 has these percentage values:

```
Views:  38.33% // Article's views divided by all articles' combined views (92 / 240)
Likes:  0%     // Article's likes divided by all articles' combined likes (0 / 6)
Shares: 40%    // Article's likes divided by all articles' combined shares (2 / 5)
Total:  78.33  // Calculation: 38.33 + 0 + 40
```

Article 1 will have "trending points" of 78.33. Doing this for all articles should provide the following outcome:

```
[0] => "Article 3" // 86.25
[1] => "Article 1" // 78.33
[2] => "Article 2" // 59.16
[3] => "Article 4" // 56.25
[4] => "Article 5" // 19.99
```

How do I make such MySQL query?

Comment: Define what an "optimal 'trending query' is and perhaps someone could help you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I just did :)

Answer (score 0):

Views are always predictable, so I suggest you keep track of how much percentage likes and shares of views.

Answer (score 0):

How much optimal I did not get, However to get exactly trending output this is what I will do:

```
create table articles (id integer, title varchar, views integer);
create table likes (id integer, articleID integer);
create table shares(id integer, articleID integer, type varchar);
insert into articles(id,title,views)values(1,'Article 1',92);
insert into articles(id,title,views)values(2,'Article 2',14);
insert into articles(id,title,views)values(3,'Article 3',39);
insert into articles(id,title,views)values(4,'Article 4',87);
insert into articles(id,title,views)values(5,'Article 5',8);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(1,2);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(2,3);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(3,2);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(4,5);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(5,3);
insert into likes(id,articleID) values(6,3);
insert into shares(id, articleID, type)values(1,1,'facebook');
insert into shares(id, articleID, type)values(2,3,'facebook');
insert into shares(id, articleID, type)values(3,1,'twitter');
insert into shares(id, articleID, type)values(4,4,'twitter');
insert into shares(id, articleID, type)values(5,2,'facebook');

select A.id, A.title,COALESCE(
A.views+(select count(id) from likes where id=A.id group by id)
+(select count(*) from shares where articleid = A.id 
group by articleid),0) as Freq 
from articles A order by Freq desc;

 id |   title   | freq 
----+-----------+------
  1 | Article 1 |   95
  4 | Article 4 |   89
  3 | Article 3 |   41
  2 | Article 2 |   16
  5 | Article 5 |    0
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured this out using query below:

```
SELECT      articles.id,
            articles.title,
            (
              coalesce(articles.views / A.totalViews, 0) +
              coalesce((SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE articleID = articles.id) / L.totalLikes, 0) +
              coalesce((SELECT count(*) FROM shares WHERE articleID = articles.id) / S.totalShares, 0)
              ) * 100 as trendingPoints
FROM        articles
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT sum(views) as totalViews FROM articles) A
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT count(*) as totalLikes FROM likes) L
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT count(*) as totalShares FROM shares) S
GROUP BY    articles.id
ORDER BY    trendingPoints DESC
```

Is this optimal or can it be written more efficiently?